# Dictionary entry not working as intended, only last entry getting inserted-Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Working on this for learning experience. The 3 ideas below I came up with

A) User creates a profile so I have a dictionary for fname and lname.

B)Then I randomly generate userid add that to a list. This list only contains random user id that I will user later eg: userid012,userid89

C) I assign A and B in a new dictionary. Output looks like this:

used_id user3
profile {'lastname': 'jon', 'firstname': 'jme'}

problem: I only see the last values user id and names. If I have more than 2 entries, I do not see the 1st ones. Helpful hint would be really helpful. 
Thank You.

```
import random

print('Enter choice 1-3:'),'\n'
print('', '1-Create new profile','\n',
      '2-Update existing profile','\n',
      '3-Delete a profile')

#global variables
choice=int(input())
user_directory={}


#Dictionary function that takes fst and lst name and puts in a dict:
def new_profile():
    new_profile={}
    fn=input('First name:')
    new_profile['firstname']=fn
    ln = input('Last name:')
    new_profile['lastname'] = ln

    for k,v in new_profile.items():
        new_profile[k]=v

        return new_profile

#Generates a random user id which we will assign to a user created above
def user_id():
    uid_list=[]
    user_id='user'+str(random.randint(0,101))

    uid_list.append(user_id)
    if(user_id in uid_list):
        uid_list.remove(user_id)
        user_id = 'user' + str(random.randint(0, 101))

        uid_list.append(user_id)
    return user_id

#This dictionary will have user id and associate created new_profile
def addToDict():
    #user_directory={} unable to use this making it global
    user_directory['used_id']=user_id()
    user_directory['profile']=new_profile()

    for key,value in user_directory.items():
        user_directory[key]=value

    return user_directory


if(choice==1):
  # myuser=addToDict() this appraoch did not work
   #addToDict>> adding it here will not get this option in while loop, put inside while
   while True:
        addToDict()
        print('Add another entry?')
        choice=input()
        #Put the line below to see if number increases
        print('Current', len(user_directory)-1)
        if(choice!='stop'):
          continue

        else:
            break

   for k,v in user_directory.items():
        print(k,v)
```

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains a couple of bugs. I can only guess what you want to do. Lets start with the obvious: The function `addToDict()` should probably add a new user to the dictionary.

What you usually want is to have a dictionary which maps a user_id onto a profile:

```
def addUserToDict(user_dictionary, user_id, profile):
    user_directory[user_id] = profile
```

And then in the input loop below you call this function with your dictionary, a new user id and a new profile.

A second bug is in `user_id()`: You always return a list with one new element, with a new random user id. And you always discard the first generated user id and then you add a second one.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will try those ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Bad indentation in the last line of `new_profile()`. The `return` is running on the first iteration. Try:

```
for k,v in new_profile.items():
    new_profile[k]=v

return new_profile
```

Btw, you don't seem to be following most conventions/standards in Python. Take a look at [this simple tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pep8-tutorial-python-code) about PEP, the official style guide. This way you can make better looking code and we can help faster :)